# Prevent particular column insert in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase

What i am trying to achieve is as follows.
I have a column "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

I have made following change

```
<changeSet dbms="mariadb" id="add-default-timestamp" author="TEST">
    <modifyDataType tableName="TABLE_X"
                    columnName="CREATED_TIMESTAMP"
                    newDataType="TIMESTAMP(3)"
    />
</changeSet>
```

Now I have added default value as current timestamp. What I want is to avoid insert/update for this column.
How can I achieve it using hibernate/liquibase

Comment: I guess you still want to query that column?

Answer (score 1):

If you have mapped this column to an entity you can use the `Column` annotation:

```
@Column(insertable = false, updateable = false)
private Timestamp createdTimestamp;
```